# How to Calculate estimated time remaining in downloading Using Xceed.Ftp.FtpClient() in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am downloading FTP files using Xceed.Ftp.FtpClient() how can i calculated the estimated remaining Time?

Dim HostName As String = (New Uri(RemoteFilePath).Host).ToString()

```
        Dim RemoteFolderName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName((New Uri(RemoteFilePath).LocalPath).ToString())

        Dim RemoteFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName((New Uri(RemoteFilePath).LocalPath).ToString())

        Dim LocalFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName((New Uri(LocalFilePath).LocalPath).ToString())

        Dim Ftp As New Xceed.Ftp.FtpClient()
        Dim AuthMethod As AuthenticationMethod = AuthenticationMethod.Tls
        Dim VeriFlag As VerificationFlags = VerificationFlags.None
        Dim Cert As Certificate = Nothing
        Ftp.Connect(HostName, 990, AuthMethod, VeriFlag, Cert)
        'Console.WriteLine("Connected")

            Ftp.Login(username, pass)
            Dim s As String = Ftp.GetCurrentFolder()
            'Console.WriteLine("LogedIn")
            Ftp.ChangeCurrentFolder("WindowsPatches/" & RemoteFolderName)
            'Console.WriteLine("Remote Folder Name:" & RemoteFolderName)
            'Ftp.ChangeCurrentFolder(RemoteFolderName)
            Dim files = Ftp.GetFolderContents()
            If files IsNot Nothing AndAlso files.Count >= 0 Then
                For index = 0 To files.Count - 1
                    If files.Item(index).Type = FtpItemType.File Then
                        RemoteFileName = files.Item(index).Name
                        LocalFileName = RemoteFileName

                        If Not Directory.Exists(RemoteFolderName) Then
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(RemoteFolderName)
                        End If
                        LocalFileName = RemoteFolderName & "\" & LocalFileName
                        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LocalFilePath) AndAlso System.IO.File.Exists(LocalFilePath) Then
                            System.IO.File.Delete(LocalFilePath)
                        End If
                        'Console.WriteLine("Downloading started...")
                        Ftp.ReceiveFile(RemoteFileName, LocalFileName)
                        'Console.WriteLine("Downloading Complete")
                        'Console.WriteLine("Working Path" & Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

                        Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
                        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(LocalFilePath & RemoteFolderName)
                        'Console.WriteLine("Local Directory Name: " & LocalFilePath & RemoteFolderName)
                        psi.CreateNoWindow = True
                        psi.FileName = RemoteFileName
                        psi.UseShellExecute = True
                        Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(psi)
                        Console.WriteLine("Update process started...")
                        'Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                'LocalFileName = RemoteFileName
            End If
```

I am using this code, any suggestion please?

Comment: Use the https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-ftp-for-activex/webframe.html#ReceivingFile_event.html Receiving File Event to get the file size then check size of current file and you get remaining size to download and check every second you get average download speed per second

Comment: Thanks Mederic, Its worked
https://xceed.com/forums/topic/FileTransferStatus-for-sFTP/

Comment: No problem glad could point you in the right direction